# How to hide a div which is opened dynamically by clicking on a button using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to close the div which is opened dynamic html. I'm not understanding where the problem is going on. I'm not even getting toggling of the div. Can any one help me this? This is the table in which i had opened a bootstrap accordion when clicking in the arrow on the table. After accordion is opened in the accordion by clicking on the edit option I'm getting the dynamical html to display. after getting display I'm not getting it closed by clicking on the cancel button or rather even getting a toggle also..

```js
$('.hidden-portfolio').hide();
$(".hidden-tr").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.hidden-portfolio').hide();
  var dynamic_html = $('#dynamic-content').html();
  dynamic_html = '<td colspan="6">' + dynamic_html + '</td>';
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(href).replaceWith(dynamic_html);
  $(href).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr align="center">
        <td align="left" class="table-heading">ICICI Pru Dynamic(G)</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>199.6</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>XXXX</td>
        <td>15.69%</td>
        <td>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            <img class="down-arow" src="images/down-grey.png">
          </a>
          <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse colapsed-data" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="card-block">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr align="center" style="background: #d9dade;">
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>type</th>
                      <th>quntity</th>
                      <th>price</th>
                      <th>VALUE</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="background: #eeeff3;">
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Jan 16,2014</td>
                      <td>SIP</td>
                      <td>12.6150</td>
                      <td>360.0225</td>
                      <td>2,700.00</td>
                      <td class="edit-delete-icons">
                        <a href="#hidden-portfolio-1" class="hidden-tr"><img src="images/pencil.png"></a>
                        <a class="image-delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;" id="hidden-portfolio-1" class="hidden-portfolio edit-hidden-portfolio"></tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Jan 16,2014</td>
                      <td>SIP</td>
                      <td>12.6150</td>
                      <td>360.0225</td>
                      <td>2,700.00</td>
                      <td class="edit-delete-icons">
                        <a href="#hidden-portfolio-2" class="hidden-tr"><img src="images/pencil.png"></a>
                        <a class="image-delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;" id="hidden-portfolio-2" class="hidden-portfolio edit-hidden-portfolio"></tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Jan 16,2014</td>
                      <td>SIP</td>
                      <td>12.6150</td>
                      <td>360.0225</td>
                      <td>2,700.00</td>
                      <td class="edit-delete-icons">
                        <a href="#hidden-portfolio-3" class="hidden-tr"><img src="images/pencil.png"></a>
                        <a class="image-delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;" id="hidden-portfolio-3" class="hidden-portfolio edit-hidden-portfolio"></tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Jan 16,2014</td>
                      <td>SIP</td>
                      <td>12.6150</td>
                      <td>360.0225</td>
                      <td>2,700.00</td>
                      <td class="edit-delete-icons">
                        <a href="#hidden-portfolio-4" class="hidden-tr"><img src="images/pencil.png"></a>
                        <a class="image-delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;" id="hidden-portfolio-4" class="hidden-portfolio edit-hidden-portfolio"></tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Jan 16,2014</td>
                      <td>SIP</td>
                      <td>12.6150</td>
                      <td>360.0225</td>
                      <td>2,700.00</td>
                      <td class="edit-delete-icons">
                        <a href="#hidden-portfolio-5" class="hidden-tr"><img src="images/pencil.png"></a>
                        <a class="image-delete" href="#"><img src="images/delete.png"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;" id="hidden-portfolio-5" class="hidden-portfolio edit-hidden-portfolio"></tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="hide-data" id="dynamic-content">
  <div class="hide-data edit-hidden-portfolio">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr style="background: #8b8b8b;">
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mutual Fund</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ICICI Pru Dynamic(G)" required />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group transaction-form-select">
                <label>Transaction</label>
                <select>
                    <option selected disabled hidden>Recommend</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                    <option value="4">Four</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="250" required />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control date-form" placeholder="16 JUl 2014" required />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control price-form" placeholder="4300.00" required />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="row form-group button-pair">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class=" save-btn">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn close-accordian cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** and verifiable code.

Comment: document.getElementById(something).style.visibility="hidden"; visibility: collapse; for tables also works

Comment: jQuery("#id").css('display','none');

Comment: `$('#el').hide();`??? and what is the use case of it `var href = $(this).attr('href');` because `tr` don't have `href` attributes.

Comment: I want to hide the div when click on the button which is opened when clicking on the image in under action i was opening the div i want to close that one using button cancel in it